# Connect my Windows XP to Mac OS X Internet Sharing

Tags: windows, internet-sharing

I have Internet Sharing enabled:
[image]
[image]

The WEP password is `aaaaa`. I understand that my MacBook Pro now acts as a wireless access point. My Windows XP PC can see this. However, when I enter `aaaaa` as a password, I can't connect `:(`

Am I missing something? I've read about WEP being seriously outdated, that WiFi device manufacturers hadn't yet agreed on a unified way to treat passwords through WEP.

So I did some experiments. As a control setup, I'll hold my Mac password to `aaaaa` or `AAAAA` at all times. I've tried the following passwords on my Windows:

Mac password: `aaaaa`
`aaaaa` - Fail
`6161616161` - Fail (`61` is the hex ASCII code for `a`)

Mac password: `AAAAA`
`AAAAA` - Fail
`4141414141` - Fail (`41` is the hex ASCII code for `A`)

## UPDATE

Yes, I also tried using 128-bit WEP, trying out the same experiments above for `aaaaaaaaaaaaa` and `AAAAAAAAAAAAA`. It still fails.

Comment: Have you been able to connect with anything else?

Comment: One layer at a time: Get it working without any encryption first.  When that works, then add encryption.

Comment: @JRobert, yes, I got it working without encryption before I posted this question :)

Comment: Good, that's useful to know. Is there another security mode than WEP available to both machines, that you can try?

Comment: @JRobert, Mac OS X sharing supports only WEP (40-bit and 128-bit). I have also successfully connected a smartphone. I think Windows and Mac haven't come to terms with how to treat WEP passwords (hex, plaintext, or otherwise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Mac:

-- Use 128-bit encryption. (Windows has 64 and 128, Apple has 40 and 128.)

-- Use a 13-character password.

On the PC:

-- Under "Wireless Security Type", select "Use Static WEP keys".

-- And finally, under "Access Point Authentication:", select "Shared".

Answer (score 2):

WOOHOO! think I finally solved the problem.

From the taskbar I right-clicked on the MacOSX network and hit configure...(which now shows up as properties...) and saw that the security type had defaulted to none even though encryption type was still set to WEP.  I changed the security type to Shared and it now works.  It took a few minutes to register the network and only once I changed it to a home network did the internet connectivity kick in.  A 40bit wep key works fine, ABC12 or 4142433131...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 128bit WEP? Even though it says 40 bit is more compatible, switching might work.

Also, make sure that any drivers on the XP machine are up to date. If the XP machine has a vendor-specific networking application, try connecting using that instead of XP's built-in wireless menu, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, I also tried 128-bit WEP. Still to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

Try 40-bit WEP with password length of 10 characters. My MBP WEP key is  1234567890 and it works.

---

[image]

I disabled my internet sharing in this pic.

Comment: How did you input the password on your MBP? `1234567890`, `$1234567890`, or `0x1234567890`?

Comment: just 1234567890 NO prefixes

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked Mac Shared to Windows XP.  Frustrating.

The problem I was having is that the key HAS to be 13 
numbers with no spaces or letters.

Example - (4253648725908)
Key is Not (Barney1233254) or (cb2535734825c)

---

Mac Setup

System Preferences - Sharing - Internet Sharing - Airport - Airport Options

Channel Automatic

Check on Enable Encryption

Password is (13 NUMBERS) only.. no letters
(kept trying to put a letter in the key and Windows will not
connect with a letter in the password under any circumstance)

WEP key length is 128-bit

Click OK and Start Internet Sharing with Internet Sharing check box

---

Windows XP PC

Bring up Wireless Connections window showing nearby wifi networks.

Click on Change the Order of Preferred Networks (not what I would think)

A new unfamiliar window opens called Wireless Network Connection Properties; this is correct

Click on the ADD button and a new window called Wireless Network Properties appears

Association Tab

Type the exact name of Mac Wifi network in Network Name SSID

Select Network Authentication as Shared

Select Data Encryption as WEP

Uncheck the Key is provided for me and the Network Key line turns on

Type the Network Key of (13 numbers) in the Network Key line

Retype the Network Key of (13 numbers) in the Confirm Network Key line

DO NOT check the ad-hoc network check box - leave blank

Click OK and Click OK again

Bring up Wireless Connections window showing nearby wifi networks.

Click on your Mac network which should show in the wifi list.

It should work straightaway.